# Web parts in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I wonder if there's a limit in SharePoint about the number of WebParts I can have in a page. Also, if a web part zone has some kind of limit, or if a page can only have a certain number of web part zones.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits as far as I can tell on the SharePoint or ASP.NET side of things.

Of course, you'll get into the limits of what can fit in a page (horizontally or vertically), but that is another matter.